# Big Commerce - Shop by Price Algorithm

Tags: bigcommerce

The current algorithm for computing the "tiers" in the Big Commerce "Shop by Price" filter yields some jagged results (i.e. 0~$794.00, $794.00~$1138.00, and so on.)  Is there a way to alter this algorithm to yield more even-numbered tiers?

Answer (score 0):

The logic for calculating Shop by Price tiers pulls from the core BC app and can't be modified. If you wanted to change the way price tiers are broken out client-side, you could replace the built-in {{shop_by_price}} using JavaScript on the frontend. The difference is you'd essentially be building your own vs modifying the existing logic.